# Need help in understanding Unknown crashes stacktraces in Google Maps SDK reported on Crashlytics

Tags: android, google-maps, crashlytics

I'm receiving multiple crashes related to Google Maps SDK in crashlytics that I'm unable to understand the stacktrace?

Google Map Version 18.1.0

Following is the stack trace

Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.bq.v()' on a null object reference

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.bq.v()' on a null object reference
       at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.cm.h(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@234154070@23.41.54 (200306-0):3)
       at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.o.bb(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@234154070@23.41.54 (200306-0):125)
       at m.fi.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@234154070@23.41.54 (200306-0):21)
       at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:1064)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.maps.zza.zzc(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@18.1.0:2)
       at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzk.onLowMemory(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@18.1.0:2)
       at com.google.android.gms.maps.zzau.onLowMemory(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@18.1.0:1)
       at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.DeferredLifecycleHelper.onLowMemory(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.0.1:1)
       at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onLowMemory(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@18.1.0:1)
       at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performLowMemory(Fragment.java:3142)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchLowMemory(FragmentManager.java:2949)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.lambda$new$1(FragmentManager.java:448)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.$r8$lambda$OSbytOFWiBhg-JuC-68xxqeOPrI(FragmentManager.java)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$$InternalSyntheticLambda$0$068c9ea6f75aed29eabb5700a8433fb9d14c27fb8935f2afb11caf64187ac04f$1.accept(FragmentManager.java:4)
       at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.onTrimMemory(ComponentActivity.java:895)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleTrimMemory(ActivityThread.java:6382)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:253)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread.lambda$scheduleTrimMemory$0(ActivityThread.java:1707)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread$$ExternalSyntheticLambda3.accept(:8)
       at com.android.internal.util.function.pooled.PooledLambdaImpl.doInvoke(PooledLambdaImpl.java:281)
       at com.android.internal.util.function.pooled.PooledLambdaImpl.invoke(PooledLambdaImpl.java:204)
       at com.android.internal.util.function.pooled.OmniFunction.run(OmniFunction.java:97)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7886)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:568)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1045)
```

Comment: What about the NullPointerException? @Computable

Comment: This looks like a similar stacktrace with https://issuetracker.google.com/247981812 have you tried updating the Maps SDK to the latest version of 18.2?

Comment: No, I haven't tried 18.2.0. I checked the above link, and I think it's occurring due to old fragment version.

Comment: Can you try the latest version and see if crashes are still recurring.

Comment: I'll add an update here as our release process is quite longer @Yrll